# Android - Remove watermark from custom camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I am working on the custom camera in android. When i take picture, some of the devices like Galaxy A80 adds watermark on the image. Since i am making the custom camera, is there any option for removing/disabling the option for watermark. I have also attached the screenshot of the watermark for the reference.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution for the problem? I'm having the same issue and I don't know how to fix it :(

Answer (score 0):

Go to the settings menu, scroll to the bottom of the list and select the watermark options.Turn it off. If problem persists, try turning on developer options first, then repeating the process.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but can I do this programatically?